# Using Javascript to change a value in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input id="NameAjax" class="ac_input" type="text" value="">
```

And using jquery:

```
).click(function(e) { 
document.getElementById("NameAjax").value = 1;
}
```

But after the click the value does not change:

```
<input id="NameAjax" class="ac_input" type="text" value="">
```

I am looking for the output to look exactly like:

```
<input id="NameAjax" class="ac_input" type="text" value="1">
```

> How to fix it ?

Comment: What is the click event bound to? Isn't the output correct?

Comment: Doesn't it have to be a string?

Comment: Are you using view source to check if it changed?

Comment: You better not use `attr` to set value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned Jquery so I am going to assume you are using it. If so try this:

```
$('#NameAjax').attr('value','1')
```

The first part `$('#NameAjax')` selects the input and the second `attr('value','1')` sets the value attribute to 1

Comment: You should use `val` not `attr`.

Comment: or just `$("#NameAjax").val(1)`

Comment: new to Jquery didn't know about the .val() method. Good to know thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#elementID").on('click', function() {
    $("#NameAjax").val('1');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `val` method:

```
$('#NameAjax').val('1');
```

Don't use jquery only half the way. And don't use `attr` function to set a value.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("element_idOrclass").click(function() { 
    $("#NameAjax").attr("value","1");
}
```

Comment: @gdorn sorry ! after post the answer i see already 3 correct answer !! :)