# Error javascript can not get value from attribute value

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.submit').click(function(){
         var value = $('#Name').attr('value');
        alert(value); 
    });  
});
<input type="text" value="10" id="Name"/>Hello world
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit"/>
```

> Result is  "Hello World", I want get value is "10", how to fix it ?

Comment: It gives 10 on my computer. Which JQuery version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting `Hello World`, but to retrieve an input's value, use the `val()` function

```
var value = $('#Name').val();
```

You don't have a second input on your page anywhere with an id of "Name", do you?

---

Also, depending on what you want to do, you may be better off handler the **form**'s submit event, rather than the submit button's click handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
         var value = $('#Name').val();
        alert(value); 
    });  
});
```

Comment: Don't know why everyone use `attr` for value [today](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8905006/601179)

Comment: Don't know why they submit forms using click event on a button!

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle of **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/NvWnz/)**,